# Implementing Bing Pixel (UET Tag) on React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, analytics

My task was to implement Microsoft's UET Tag on every page within a react app. I successfully added it to the defaultLayout component to ensure that the function setting the UET Tag is run on every page. However, there seems to be a problem as the tag only appears on every other page. For instance, it would appear on page 1, but not on page 2. It would then show up again when moving from page 2 to page 3. However, when going back to page 1 from page 3, the tag does not appear. To confirm if the UET Tag is running, I was instructed to use the UET Tag Helper.

Here is the code:

**defaultLayout.js**

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";

const DefaultLayout = () => {

    const analytics = {
        bing: `Bing-ID-Goes-Here`
    }

    const createUETScript = async () => {
        if (!!document.getElementById(`bing-${analytics.bing}`)) {
            document.getElementById(`bing-${analytics.bing}`).remove();

        }

        var scriptParent = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.id = `bing-${analytics.bing}`;

        script.text = `(function(w,d,t,r,u){var f,n,i;w[u]=w[u]||[],f=function(){var o={ti:"${analytics.bing}"};o.q=w[u],w[u]=new UET(o),w[u].push("pageLoad")},n=d.createElement(t),n.src=r,n.async=1,n.onload=n.onreadystatechange=function(){var s=this.readyState;s&&s!=="loaded"&&s!=="complete"||(f(),n.onload=n.onreadystatechange=null)},i=d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0],i.parentNode.insertBefore(n,i)})(window,document,"script","//bat.bing.com/bat.js","uetq");`
        // Note that the text script was given by the client and that the only modification made was setting the ID to a variable rather than being fixed
        script.setAttribute("async", "async");

        scriptParent.parentNode.insertBefore(script, scriptParent);

        console.log(`Bing Pixel: ${analytics.bing}`);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        createUETScript();
    },[]);

    return <div>
        <Outlet/>
    </div>
}
```